# .NET 4.5 HttpClient PUT or POST over SSL always fails

Tags: .net, ssl, asp.net-web-api, httpclient, async-await

I am having a terrible time troubleshooting this issue.  I'm also having a terrible time reproducing it consistently from one application to another.

Under certain circumstances, which I cannot seem to identify, making `PUT` and `POST` calls using the `HttpClient` results in the following exception.

> An error occurred while sending the request.
>
> Inner Exception:
>   The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
>
> Inner Exception:
>   This operation cannot be performed on a completed asynchronous result object.

Everything seems to work with HTTP, this only happens on HTTPS.

Certificates are valid, but I have tried setting the `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (s, c, ch, es) => true;`

I have tried setting `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue = false;`

I have tried, what seems like a million, other things ranging from headers, authentication, etc.

Does anyone have any idea what else I can check, try, etc?

Code snippet:

```
// this is my registration in my IoC container...
var handler = new HttpClientHandler
{
    UseDefaultCredentials = true,
    Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials,
};

var client = HttpClientFactory.Create(handler);
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Properties.Settings.Default.BaseUrl);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-CustomHeader", "value");

// _client is constructor injected into my class...
var response = await _client.PutAsJsonAsync("api/resource/" + id, model).ConfigureAwait(false);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); // <-- never executes...
```

**UPDATE:**

If I take off the `ConfigureAwait(false)` it works fine.

Note, this is a WPF app, specifically, this is a Visual Studio extension.  However, I do have an ASP.NET MVC 4 application with the exact same problem, and that application does not call `ConfigureAwait(false)` at all...

**UPDATE 2:**

I updated the code snippet to include the instantiation of the `HttpClient` class. The only thing that is not included in the code snippet is the model type and declaration.  It should be irrelevant, as it is a serializable class with all auto properties with no complex types.

**UPDATE 3:**

I don't know if this is relevant, but I have found a few things which look weird to me.

When executing the above code, in Fiddler, I get a `401` on the `POST`, followed by 2 `CONNECT`'s which result in the following HTTP responses:

> HTTP/1.1 200 Connection Established
>   Connection: close

**UPDATE 4:**

I changed my IoC registration code to be this:

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler
{
    UseDefaultCredentials = true,
    Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials,
};

var client = HttpClientFactory.Create(handler);
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Properties.Settings.Default.BaseUrl);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-CustomHeader", "value");
```

and now it fails, but when I open Fiddler and let it decrypt traffic ... it works!

**UPDATE 5:**

I believe this must be a server issue, or a cert issue.  Any tips on what to check from here would be greatly appreciated.  Certs are valid and issued from a trusted CA.

**UPDATE 6:**

More debugging and troubleshooting.  The exception occurs before the `ServicePointManager` `CertificateValidationCallback` is invoked.

Comment: Show an excerpt of the actual sending code.

Comment: Added code snippet, but it is really just basic usage.  Nothing fancy.

Comment: Are you disposing `_client` before the request completes? Can you post a minimal repro?

Comment: @StephenCleary No, not disposing it.  Using the same instance for the life of my application. Added an update with some more code, but it is seriously a very simple use.

Comment: Having a similar issue.  I removed the await, just to see if the call fires.  It does when the await is not present.  Does not fire when the await is present.  Never leaves the server.

Comment: @BrianP I'm convinced its a bug in HttpClient, or a handler now.  I tested using pure old school WebRequest code and it works fine, even using async/await.

Comment: No, I wrote my own HttpClient using the basic WebRequest objects.

Comment: I switch those requests to use [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) and it worked as expected ...

Comment: Were you ever able to resolve this? I'm noticing a similar issue when running a visual studio load test which calls a test method that issues a PATCH instead of a PUT. I'm not able to repro this otherwise.

Comment: I hope someone from MSFT is monitoring this. This is easily reproducible by wrapping the HttpClient call to Put/Post over SSL in a Parallel.For

Comment: Never resolved, I just used my own wrapper using WebRequest objects.  Really the only difference is the pipelining of the delegate handlers.  I don't need that in my use case, but it would be pretty easy to implement if I did

Comment: I recall hearing about bugs like this in `HttpClient` some time ago (long before .NET 4.5.1). Perhaps these bugs have been fixed in the meantime, but it doesn't surprise me you're finding them. See if .NET 4.5.1 works for you, and if not, you'll probably have to use the older `WebRequest` classes.

Answer (score 2):

I just got done troubleshooting a similar issue with HttpClient. It turns out I was receiving an SNI warning during the SSL handshake, which caused HttpClient to lock up indefinitely. Try running WireShark/tcpdump and see if you are getting a TLSv1 Unrecognized Name warning, or any other kind of handshake warning. HttpClient does not appear to handle these properly based on my tests.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I resolved it installing the last updated of the .NET framework (4.5).