# Consuming Web API from MVC4 controller?

Tags: rest, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am currently working on a website and I had a good separation of concerns following a repository pattern with repositories and managers. Now, I am attempting to implement a Web API as I would greatly benefit from it in the future being able to use it from various clients. Since I am fairly new to REST services, I am having trouble with the correct procedure to consume my web API from a Service in my MVC4 application to then use that service in my MVC controllers. I do not want to have to use knockout for every call to the API.

My Web APIs look something like this(simplified):

```
public class UserController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IUserManager _manager;

    public UserController(IUserManager manager)
    {
        this._manager = manager;
    }

    // GET api/user
    public IEnumerable<User> Get()
    {
        return _manager.GetAll();
    }

    // GET api/user/5
    public User Get(int id)
    {
        return _manager.GetById(id);
    }

    // POST api/user
    public void Post(User user)
    {
        _manager.Add(user);
    }

    // PUT api/user/5
    public void Put(User user)
    {
        _manager.Update(user);
    }

    // DELETE api/user/5
    public void Delete(User user)
    {
        _manager.Delete(user);
    }
}
```

I essentially would like to create a service to consume my web API as such:

```
public class UserService : IUserService
{
    ....Implement something to get,post,put,and delete using the api.
}
```

so then I can use it in my mvc controller:

```
public class UserController: Controller
{
    private readonly IUserService _userService;

    public UserController(IUserService userService)
    {
        this._userService = userService;
    }
    //And then I will be able to communicate with my WebAPI from my MVC controller
}
```

I know this is possible because I have seen it done at some workplaces but it is very difficult to find articles about this, I have only found articles explaining how to consume web API through knockout. Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the implementation over here: https://github.com/NBusy/NBusy.SDK/blob/master/src/NBusy.Client/Resources/Messages.cs

It basically makes use of `HttpClient` class to consume Web API. One caveat though, all responses are wrapped in a custom `HttpResponse` class in that sample. You don't need to do that and can simply use the retrieved DTO object as the return type or a raw `HttpResponseMessage` class.

Comment: This is just what I was looking for. Well, at least the start to it. Thank you very much. Just one more question that I hope you could answer for me. Do I have to run my API separately for this to work? Or host it? I am at least 80% sure that I should be able to run my entire solution (including MVC4 app and WebApi's) and be able to hit the API correct?

Comment: Nope, not at all. I needed to separate the backend from the frontend for that particular project but nothing stops you from having both the API & MVC in the same project.

Comment: Okay, I will look through your project some more. So you are saying that by running my solution with the **MVC Project as the startup project** should be enough to be able to hit the API?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to create a static class, I created a separate Class Library to use across solutions that might want to use the API.

NOTE: I use RestSharp for POST and PUT operation since I haven't been able to get them to work using the regular `HttpClient` over SSL. As you can see documented in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17117105/net-4-5-httpclient-put-or-post-over-ssl-always-fails#comment26083256_17117105).

```
internal static class Container
{
    private static bool isInitialized;
    internal static HttpClient Client { get; set; }
    internal static RestClient RestClient { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Verifies the initialized.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="throwException">if set to <c>true</c> [throw exception].</param>
    /// <returns>
    ///     <c>true</c> if it has been initialized; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
    /// </returns>
    /// <exception cref="System.InvalidOperationException">Service must be initialized first.</exception>
    internal static bool VerifyInitialized(bool throwException = true)
    {
        if (!isInitialized)
        {
            if (throwException)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Service must be initialized first.");
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes the Service communication, all methods throw a System.InvalidOperationException if it hasn't been initialized.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="url">The URL.</param>
    /// <param name="connectionUserName">Name of the connection user.</param>
    /// <param name="connectionPassword">The connection password.</param>
    internal static void Initialize(string url, string connectionUserName, string connectionPassword)
    {
        RestClient = new RestClient(url);
        if (connectionUserName != null && connectionPassword != null)
        {
            HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler
            {
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential(connectionUserName, connectionPassword)
            };
            Client = new HttpClient(handler);
            RestClient.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(connectionUserName, connectionPassword);
        }
        else
        {
            Client = new HttpClient();
        }
        Client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
        isInitialized = true;
    }
}

public static class UserService
{
    public static void Initialize(string url = "https://serverUrl/", string connectionUserName = null, string connectionPassword = null)
    {
        Container.Initialize(url, connectionUserName, connectionPassword);
    }

    public static async Task<IEnumerable<User>> GetServiceSites()
    {
        // RestSharp example
        Container.VerifyInitialized();
        var request = new RestRequest("api/Users", Method.GET);
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
        var response = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { return Container.RestClient.Execute<List<User>>(request); }).ConfigureAwait(false);
        return response.Data;
        // HttpClient example
        var response = await Container.Client.GetAsync("api/Users/").ConfigureAwait(false);
        return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<User>>().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    public static async Task<User> Get(int id)
    {
        Container.VerifyInitialized();
        var request = new RestRequest("api/Users/" + id, Method.GET);
        var response = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { return Container.RestClient.Execute<User>(request); }).ConfigureAwait(false);
        return response.Data;
    }

    public static async Task Put(int id, User user)
    {
        Container.VerifyInitialized();
        var request = new RestRequest("api/Users/" + id, Method.PATCH);
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
        request.AddBody(user);
        var response = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { return Container.RestClient.Execute(request); }).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    public static async Task Post(User user)
    {
        Container.VerifyInitialized();
        var request = new RestRequest("api/Users", Method.POST);
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
        request.AddBody(user);
        var response = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { return Container.RestClient.Execute(request); }).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    public static async Task Delete(int id)
    {
        Container.VerifyInitialized();
        var request = new RestRequest("api/Users/" + id, Method.DELETE);
        var response = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { return Container.RestClient.Execute(request); }).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```